# Code returns Traceback Error for unsupported operand. Cannot see the problem

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Currently doing an assignment for school. My code is coming back with errors in a couple of lines of code, and suggests I'm using Tkinter, which I have not. Looking for anyone who has time to cast their eyes over my code please.

To be able to see the errors come up, I pressed "d" to open the input window and then typed in "square" - all lower case.

I'm trying to get the program to draw a shape when you put in its name or the number of sides it has.

My error comes back as:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 701, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "E:\Master 200820 no comments Stack.py", line 85, in startUp
    mainGame()
  File "E:\Master 200820 no comments Stack.py", line 125, in mainGame
    regShapeDraw()
  File "E:\Master 200820 no comments Stack.py", line 73, in regShapeDraw
    length = ((1 / sides) * 500)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'
```

This is my code:

```
import turtle
import math
import random
import time

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Shape Shop")
screen.setup(width=500, height=700)
screen.bgcolor('lightsteelblue')

turtleS = turtle.Turtle()
turtleS.ht()
turtleS.penup()
turtleS.goto(0, 250)
turtleS.write("Welcome to the Shape Shop", align="center", font=("Avenir", 18, "bold", "underline"))


pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.pensize(2)
pen.ht()


def instructions():
    instPen = turtle.Turtle()
    instPen.ht()

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(0, 205)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write("For this game, you can:", align="center", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-120, 170)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write("• Type in the name of a shape", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-100, 145)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write("- Names must be in lowercase", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-100, 120)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write("- Shape must have 12 or less sides", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-120, 95)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write("• Type in a number of sides", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-100, 70)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write("- Number must be less than 25", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-120, 35)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write(": The program will then draw the shape", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-120, 10)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write(": And tell you what shape it is", font=("Avenir", 12))

    instPen.penup()
    instPen.goto(-240, -340)
    instPen.pendown()
    instPen.write("Shape Shop v1.0", font=("Avenir", 8))

instructions()

def regShapeDraw():
    length = ((1 / sides) * 500)
    angle = (360 / sides)
    pen.forward(length / 2)
    for i in range(sides - 1):
        pen.left(angle)
        pen.forward(length)
    pen.left(angle)
    pen.forward(length / 2)

sides = []

def startUp():
    mainGame()

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(startUp, "d")

def mainGame():
    userInput = screen.textinput("What shape do you want? ", "Enter a shape name or a number of sides: ")

    if userInput == "COOL":
        eggPen = turtle.Turtle()
        eggPen.speed(0)
        eggPen.color('black')
        eggPen.penup()
        eggPen.goto(0, -80)
        eggPen.pendown()
        rotate=int(360)
        def drawCircles(t,size):
            size = 70
            for i in range(5):
                t.circle(size)
                size=size-4
        def drawSpecial(t,size,repeat):
          for i in range (repeat):
            drawCircles(t,size)
            t.right(360/repeat)
        drawSpecial(eggPen,100,10)
        shapeName = "WOAH!"
    else:
        if userInput.isalpha():
            if userInput == "triangle":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 3
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "square":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 4
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "quadrilateral":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 4
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "pentagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 5
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "hexagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 6
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "septagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 7
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "heptagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 7
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "octagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 8
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "nonagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 9
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "decagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 10
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "hendecagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 11
                regShapeDraw()
            elif userInput == "dodecagon":
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = 12
                regShapeDraw()
            else:
                    pen.penup()
                    pen.goto(0, -250)
                    pen.pendown()
                    pen.write("We don't seem to have that shape in our database. You could try:", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))
                    pen.penup()
                    pen.goto(0, -275)
                    pen.pendown()
                    pen.write("» Making all the letters lowercase", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))
                    pen.penup()
                    pen.goto(0, -300)
                    pen.pendown()
                    pen.write("» Checking your spelling", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))
                    pen.penup()
                    pen.goto(0, -325)
                    pen.pendown()
                    pen.write("» Making sure the shape you want has 12 or less sides", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))
        elif userInput.isnumeric():
            if int(userInput) <= 25:
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -300)
                pen.pendown()
                sides = int(userInput)
                regShapeDraw()
            else:
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -250)
                pen.pendown()
                pen.write("We don't seem to have that shape in our database. You could try:", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -275)
                pen.pendown()
                pen.write("» Making the number less than 25", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))
        else:
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -250)
                pen.pendown()
                pen.write("We don't seem to have that shape in our database. You could try:", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))
                pen.penup()
                pen.goto(0, -275)
                pen.pendown()
                pen.write("» Making your input all letters or all numbers", align="center", font=("Arial", 12))

        if userInput == "3":
            shapeName = "Triangle"
        elif userInput == "4":
            shapeName = "Square"
        elif userInput == "5":
            shapeName = "Pentagon"
        elif userInput == "6":
            shapeName = "Hexagon"
        elif userInput == "7":
            shapeName = "Heptagon"
        elif userInput == "8":
            shapeName = "Octagon"
        elif userInput == "9":
            shapeName = "Nonagon"
        elif userInput == "10":
            shapeName = "Decagon"
        elif userInput == "11":
            shapeName = "Hendecagon"
        elif userInput == "12":
            shapeName = "Dodecagon"
        elif userInput == "13":
            shapeName = "Triskaidecagon"
        elif userInput == "14":
            shapeName = "Tetrakaidecagon"
        elif userInput == "15":
            shapeName = "Pentadecagon"
        elif userInput == "16":
            shapeName = "Hexakaidecagon"
        elif userInput == "17":
            shapeName = "Heptadecagon"
        elif userInput == "18":
            shapeName = "Octakaidecagon"
        elif userInput == "19":
            shapeName = "Enneadecagon"
        elif userInput == "20":
            shapeName = "Icosagon"
        elif userInput == "21":
            shapeName = "Icosikaihenagon"
        elif userInput == "22":
            shapeName = "Icosikaidigon"
        elif userInput == "23":
            shapeName = "Icosikaitrigon"
        elif userInput == "24":
            shapeName = "Icositetragon"
        elif userInput == "25":
            shapeName = "Icosikaipentagon"
        elif userInput == "triangle":
            shapeName = "Triangle"
        elif userInput == "square":
            shapeName = "Square"
        elif userInput == "quadrilateral":
            shapeName = "Square"
        elif userInput == "pentagon":
            shapeName = "Pentagon"
        elif userInput == "hexagon":
            shapeName = "Hexagon"
        elif userInput == "heptagon":
            shapeName = "Heptagon"
        elif userInput == "septagon":
            shapeName = "Heptagon"
        elif userInput == "octagon":
            shapeName = "Octagon"
        elif userInput == "nonagon":
            shapeName = "Nonagon"
        elif userInput == "decagon":
            shapeName = "Decagon"
        elif userInput == "hendecagon":
            shapeName = "Hendecagon"
        elif userInput == "dodecagon":
            shapeName = "Dodecagon"
        else:
            shapeName = "¯\(°_o)/¯"

    typeName = turtle.Turtle()
    typeName.ht()
    typeName.penup()
    typeName.goto(0, -120)
    typeName.pendown()
    typeName.write(shapeName, align="center", font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] to post the error message (starting with Traceback), and a [mcve] of the part of the code that throws the error.

Comment: As the error notes, `sides` is a list (`sides = []`). You're attempting to divide the list though when you do `1 / sides` and such. What's your intent there?

Comment: The problem is that `sides` is an empty list and you can't actually divide a `int` and a `list`. What exactly is your `length` trying to do?

Comment: Did you mean `1/len(sides)`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Wont that throw a `ZeroDivisionError` ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you for your reply. I understand what you're saying, but I don't then know how to fix it. I need the value of the 'sides' variable to be assigned later so that each shape has a different number of sides. If I give that variable a constant value such as 1, the program will always draw only that number of sides. Is there is a way that I could leave the variable blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My code is coming back with errors in a couple of lines of code, and
> suggests I'm using Tkinter, which I have not.

If you're using *turtle*, you're using *tkinter* as turtle sits atop tkinter.  As far as the error:

```
File "E:\Master 200820 no comments Stack.py", line 73, in regShapeDraw
    length = ((1 / sides) * 500)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'
```

Everywhere in your code, you treat the variable `sides` as an `int`:

```
angle = (360 / sides)
for i in range(sides - 1):
sides = 3
sides = 4
...
sides = 11
sides = 12
sides = int(userInput)
```

except in it's global value:

```
sides = []
```

Which leads to the next problem.  The function `regShapeDraw()` uses `sides` globally:

```
def regShapeDraw():
    length = ((1 / sides) * 500)
    angle = (360 / sides)
    pen.forward(length / 2)
    for i in range(sides - 1):
        pen.left(angle)
        pen.forward(length)
    pen.left(angle)
    pen.forward(length / 2)
```

But who sets `sides` globally?  It's only set once globally:

```
sides = []
```

All the other setting of `sides`, eg. in `mainGame()`, are *local*.  To make this work, you need to declare `sides` global in `mainGame()`:

```
def mainGame():
    global sides

    userInput = ...

    ...
```

and anywhere else the global `sides` is set from within a function.  In summary:

- Set the global `sides` to a reasonable default `int` value (e.g. `3`)
- Declare `sides` global in `mainGame()`
- Read about the `global` keyword in your (online) Python textbook

If/when you learn about `dict`, you should be able to make this code much more manageable.  Something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

INSTRUCTION_FONT = ('Arial', 12)
SHAPE_FONT = ('Arial', 30, 'bold')
TITLE_FONT = ('Avenir', 18, 'bold', 'underline')
VERSION_FONT = ('Arial', 8)

def instructions():
    instPen = Turtle()
    instPen.hideturtle()
    instPen.penup()

    instPen.goto(0, 205)
    instPen.write("For this game, you can:", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-120, 170)
    instPen.write("• Type in the name of a shape", font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-100, 145)
    instPen.write("- Names must be in lowercase", font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-100, 120)
    instPen.write("- Shape must have 12 or less sides", font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-120, 95)
    instPen.write("• Type in a number of sides", font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-100, 70)
    instPen.write("- Number must be less than 25", font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-120, 35)
    instPen.write(": The program will then draw the shape", font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-120, 10)
    instPen.write(": And tell you what shape it is", font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    instPen.goto(-240, -340)
    instPen.write("Shape Shop v1.0", font=VERSION_FONT)

def regShapeDraw():
    length = 1 / sides * 500
    pen.forward(length / 2)

    angle = 360 / sides

    for _ in range(sides - 1):
        pen.left(angle)
        pen.forward(length)

    pen.left(angle)
    pen.forward(length / 2)

SHAPE_NAME_TO_SIDES = {
    'triangle': 3,
    'square': 4,
    'quadrilateral': 4,
    'pentagon': 5,
    'hexagon': 6,
    'septagon': 7,
    'heptagon': 7,
    'octagon': 8,
    'nonagon': 9,
    'decagon': 10,
    'hendecagon': 11,
    'dodecagon': 12,
}

SHAPE_SIDES_TO_NAME = {
    '3': 'triangle',
    '4': 'equare',
    '5': 'pentagon',
    '6': 'hexagon',
    '7': 'heptagon',
    '8': 'octagon',
    '9': 'nonagon',
    '10': 'decagon',
    '11': 'hendecagon',
    '12': 'dodecagon',
    '13': 'triskaidecagon',
    '14': 'tetrakaidecagon',
    '15': 'pentadecagon',
    '16': 'hexakaidecagon',
    '17': 'heptadecagon',
    '18': 'octakaidecagon',
    '19': 'enneadecagon',
    '20': 'icosagon',
    '21': 'icosikaihenagon',
    '22': 'icosikaidigon',
    '23': 'icosikaitrigon',
    '24': 'icositetragon',
    '25': 'icosikaipentagon',
}

SHAPE_NAME_ALIASES = {
    'quadrilateral': 'square',
    'septagon': 'heptagon',
}

def mainGame():
    global sides

    userInput = screen.textinput("What shape do you want? ", "Enter a shape name or a number of sides:").lower()

    pen.clear()
    typeName.clear()

    if userInput.isalpha():
        if userInput in SHAPE_NAME_TO_SIDES:
            pen.penup()
            pen.goto(0, -300)
            pen.pendown()
            sides = SHAPE_NAME_TO_SIDES[userInput.lower()]
            regShapeDraw()
        else:
            pen.penup()
            pen.goto(0, -250)
            pen.write("We don't seem to have that shape in our database. You could try:", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)
            pen.sety(-275)
            pen.write("» Making all the letters lowercase", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)
            pen.sety(-300)
            pen.write("» Checking your spelling", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)
            pen.sety(-325)
            pen.write("» Making sure the shape you want has 12 or less sides", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)
    elif userInput.isnumeric():
        sides = int(userInput)

        if sides <= 25:
            pen.penup()
            pen.goto(0, -300)
            pen.pendown()
            regShapeDraw()
        else:
            pen.penup()
            pen.goto(0, -250)
            pen.write("We don't seem to have that shape in our database. You could try:", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)
            pen.sety(-275)
            pen.write("» Making the number less than 25", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)
    else:
        pen.penup()
        pen.goto(0, -250)
        pen.write("We don't seem to have that shape in our database. You could try:", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)
        pen.sety(-275)
        pen.write("» Making your input all letters or all numbers", align='center', font=INSTRUCTION_FONT)

    if userInput in SHAPE_SIDES_TO_NAME:
        shapeName = SHAPE_SIDES_TO_NAME[userInput]
    elif userInput in SHAPE_NAME_ALIASES:
        shapeName = SHAPE_NAME_ALIASES[userInput]
    elif userInput in SHAPE_NAME_TO_SIDES:
        shapeName = userInput
    else:
        shapeName = r"¯\(°_o)/¯"

    typeName.write(shapeName.title(), align='center', font=SHAPE_FONT)
    screen.listen()  # must be reasserted after screen.textinput()

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Shape Shop")
screen.setup(width=500, height=700)
screen.bgcolor('lightsteelblue')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(250)
turtle.write("Welcome to the Shape Shop", align='center', font=TITLE_FONT)

instructions()

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.pensize(2)

typeName = Turtle()
typeName.hideturtle()
typeName.penup()
typeName.sety(-120)

sides = 3

screen.onkeypress(mainGame, 'd')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```